# Does Facebook, Google Plus and another social network using OpenID share same keyset

Tags: facebook, google-plus, openid

I design database for my system that using social login. As I know, both Facebook and Google Plus using OpenID for connecting. They will return an ID. My question is: Do they share same key set? That means no id (in both facebook and google plus) can be duplicated. If this true, I can set this column in database to be unique key for constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee that Facebook IDs and Google IDs will not overlap. However it is easy to guarantee in your system by prepending a namespace.

You would convert a Facebook ID from `123` to `fb:123` and a Google ID from `123` to `g:123`.

Comment: i think if you instead put the prefix at the end (postfix) would cause a more evenly distributed key space (matters on perf once you save millions)

Comment: I’d rather use different columns for that to begin with (or normalize it to a `account-id|provider-id|provider-user-id` model). That way, users can easily use your service with different login providers of their choosing, but have them all connect to _one_ account in your app.